# cgBusy on IE9 and other legacy browsers

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I have a problem with cgBusy on IE legacy browsers and from what I managed to figure out it's because of ng-show. The code is simple and straight forward:

```
<div cg-busy="{promise:initPromise, message:'Loading...', delay:1000}"></div>
```

ng-show seems to be a regular problem with IE9 and bellow and i am using ng-if as a fix.

Has anyone had this problem and solved it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the limit of the css files in ie9. Maybe this helps someone else.